bash script with rwx bits set, but still permission denied
RHEL 7.8
I log into and use dozens of different servers.  On four of them, scripts won't execute.  Here's an example:
$ ls -aFl foo.sh 
-rwxr-xr--. 1 rjohnson dbadmin 23 May 11 15:20 foo.sh*

$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo"

$ file foo.sh
foo.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

$ ./foo.sh
-bash: ./foo.sh: Permission denied

On all the other systems that I work on, it works like a champ:
$ ls -aFl foo.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 postgres postgres 23 May 11 15:30 foo.sh*

$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo"

$ ./foo.sh
foo

Am I overlooking something obvious, or is some "clever" security-minded configuration switch preventing me from doing my job?
EDIT: added SELinux context output:
$ ls -aFlZ foo.sh
-rwxr-xr--. rjohnson dbadmin unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 foo.sh*

None of the other servers seem to have it, which means that's probably the answer.

Perhaps What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?

@steeldriver perhaps so.  See my edited question.

Is the directory tree you are in mounted without the exec option, or with the noexec option? Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

It may be a good idea to add the output of id to the question. If you are logged in as postgress and postgress is not a member of dbadmin , then it is logical that it won't work.

@waltinator it was noexec. WTH mounts /home noexec??

Check the home line in /etc/fstab. Or try sudo mount -o remount,rw /home to fix it once.

There are two easy reasons for this

/bin/bash exists but is not executable.  Or even it loader isn't executable.  If you can run /bin/bash directly, this isn't the problem.
The mount point that the script is part of has the noexec flag set.  This might well be the case if you are using network drives.  Find the relevant line in /proc/mounts to find out.

